# Question about exact differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When we are asked to solve the 1st order ODE of the form,

$M(x,y)+N(x,y)y'=0$

and given that it is exact, then there exists a function $\phi(x,y)=C$ s.t $\phi_x=M $ and $\phi_y=N$

But did we actually solve the ODE?Did we actually find a function y=y(x) explicitly or implicitly?

If the ODE is not exact, then we have to multiply an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ to make it exact, and again obtain a function $\chi(x,y)=C$

But this time the total differential of $\chi$ is not equal to the original ODE, did we actually 'solve' the ODE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to both questions.

Obviously, you find implicit solutions.